# Xcode 10.3 project Builds but returns No such file or directory

Tags: c++, xcode, file-io

I have gotten my project to build successfully in Xcode 10.3 however the input.txt file I need it to read from seems to can't find it even though I have it save in the same folder as the program. Below is the main code for this and the input.txt file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
#include "expression.h"
#include "subexpression.h"
#include "symboltable.h"
#include "parse.h"
//create an object of SymbolTable
SymbolTable symbolTable;
//prototype of the function
void parseAssignments(stringstream& in);
//define main function
int main(){
    //Variables
    Expression* expression;
    char paren, comma;
    string line;
    //create input file stream
    ifstream fin("input.txt");
    //check if the file is open
    //if file is not open error message
    if(!fin.is_open())
        perror("error with opening file!");
    //create loop to read from file content
     while(getline(fin, line)){
        symbolTable.init();
        if(!fin)
            break;
        stringstream in(line, ios_base::in);
        in >> paren;
        cout << line << " ";
        expression = SubExpression::parse(in);
        in >> comma;
        //call the function 
        parseAssignments(in);
        //display results
        int result = expression->evaluate();
        cout << "value = " << result << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
//define parseAssignments()
void parseAssignments(stringstream& in){
    char assignop, delimiter;
    string variable;
    int value;
    symbolTable.init();
    do{
        variable = parseName(in);
        in >> ws >> assignop >> value >> delimiter;
        symbolTable.insert(variable, value);        
    } 
    while (delimiter == ','); 
}
```

input.txt

```
(x+y), x = 5, y= 2; /* Expect value = 7 */
(x-y), x=3, y=1; /* Expect value = 2 */
((x+y)/(x-y)), x=6, y=2; /* Expect value = 2 */
((x/y)/(x-y)), x=20, y=2; /* Expect value = 0 */
(x*y), x=25, y=5; /* Expect value = 125 */
```

error: 
    error with opening file!: No such file or directory
    sh: pause: command not found
    Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: I'm not sure about XCode but there is absolutely no guarantee that 'same folder as the program' is the correct folder (it wouldn't be in Visual Studio for instance).

Comment: In VS what would be the correct folder?

Comment: The Project folder (which is different from the folder where the program is built).

Comment: The more or less foolproof way to find out is to write some code which **writes** a file and see where that file appears. That's the default folder.

Comment: So I made a simple output program but I couldn't find where it was sent so I changed the location preferences to be able to find it, but I am not sure it works that way for an input file to be read from.